# Filter Array Not in Another Array

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

Need to  filter one array based on another array. Is there a util function in knock out ? else i need to go with javascript

First  :

```
var obj1 = [{
    "visible": "true",
    "id": 1
}, {
    "visible": "true",
    "id": 2
}, {
    "visible": "true",
    "id": 3
}, {
    "Name": "Test3",
    "id": 4
}];
```

Second  :

```
var obj2 = [ 2,3]
```

Now i need to filter obj1 based on obj2 and return items from obj1 that are not in obj2 omittng 2,3 in the above data (Comparison on  object 1 **Id**)

output:

```
[{
    "visible": "true",
    "id": 1
}, {
    "Name": "Test3",
    "id": 4
}];
```

Answer (score 90, accepted):

You can simply run through `obj1` using `filter` and use `indexOf` on `obj2` to see if it exists. `indexOf` returns `-1` if the value isn't in the array, and `filter` includes the item when the callback returns `true`.

```
var arr = obj1.filter(function(item){
  return obj2.indexOf(item.id) === -1;
});
```

---

With newer ES syntax and APIs, it becomes simpler:

```
const arr = obj1.filter(i => !obj2.includes(i.id))
```

Answer (score 3):

Even if the answer provided by @Joseph are good, it can lead to performance issues if you have a very large array. The complexity is O(n^2), but it can be improved to O(n). Below I put the code I'd use to perform this task:

```
//create a map for storing object id
const map = new Map();
//add existing id from the array to the map
for (item of obj2) {
  map.set(item.id, true);
}

//create a new array that contains all items that aren't included in the //map
//the map lookUp is O(1) complexity
const arr = obj1.filter(item => !map[item.id]);
```

In this way we avoid nested iteration and have O(n) complexity

Answer (score -1):

To create your output array, create a function that will iterate through obj1 and populate a new array based on whether the id of every obj in the iteration exists in obj2.

```
var obj1 = [{
    "visible": "true",
    "id": 1
}, {
    "visible": "true",
    "id": 2
}, {
    "visible": "true",
    "id": 3
}, {
    "Name": "Test3",
    "id": 4
}];

var obj2 = [2,3]

var select = function(arr) {
  var newArr = [];
  obj1.forEach(function(obj) {
    if obj2.indexOf(obj.id) !== -1 {
      newArr.push(obj)
    };
  };
  return newArr;
};
```