# Get value not in array

Tags: javascript, arrays

Given two arrays: (`one` and `two`).

`one`: contains values

`two`: contains objects with values

I need to get the values from `one` which are not in `two`. I've tried with `.filter()` and `.indexOf()` but don't get the desired result.

In the following case I expect `result` to have the value `333`. How to achieve that?

```js
var one = [111, 222, 333, 444];
var two = [
  { identifier: 111 },
  { identifier: 222 },
  { identifier: 444 }
];

var result = two.filter(function (item) {
    console.log(item.identifier, one.indexOf(item.identifier));
});

console.log('result: ', result);
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Filter Array Not in Another Array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33577868/filter-array-not-in-another-array)

Comment: Or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2963281/javascript-algorithm-to-find-elements-in-array-that-are-not-in-another-array may be better

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just do what you want, filter `one` and take only those which are not in `two` (find it in `two`, if found it will return the object i.e. `true` equivalent if not found then it will return `undefined` i.e. `false`  equivalent and negate `!` it)

```js
var one = [111, 222, 333, 444];
var two = [
  { identifier: 111 },
  { identifier: 222 },
  { identifier: 444 }
];
var resultArr = one.filter(function(val){
    return !two.find(function(obj){
        return val===obj.identifier;
    });
});

console.log(resultArr)
```

Answer (score 2):

I would extract the identifier values from `two` and then run the filter over `one`:

```js
var one = [111, 222, 333, 444];
var two = [
  { identifier: 111 },
  { identifier: 222 },
  { identifier: 444 }
];

// get a flattened array of identifier values [111, 222, 444]
const identifiers = two.map((item) => item.identifier);

var result = one.filter(function (item) {
    console.log(item, identifiers.indexOf(item) === -1);
    return identifiers.indexOf(item) === -1;
});

console.log('result: ', result);
```

Comment: looks complicated but gives the right result! thank you! +1

Comment: if `two` contains an item not in `one` does this still work?, sorry never mind re read the question and see he wants the ones in `one`

Comment: @Quince yes it will produce the same output.

Answer (score 2):

You do not `return` a `Boolean` value from `.filter()`.

You can iterate `one` array and can use `.some()` and `!` operator to check if the current value exists at `two` array `"identifier"` property

```js
var one = [111, 222, 333, 444];
var two = [
  { identifier: 111 },
  { identifier: 222 },
  { identifier: 444 }
];

var result = one.filter(function (item) {
    return !two.some(function(el) {
      return el.identifier === item
    })
});

console.log('result: ', result);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can filter the array `one` returning the elements that are not found in array `two`.

Code:

```js
const one = [111, 222, 333, 444];
const two = [{identifier: 111},{identifier: 222},{identifier: 444}];
const result = one.filter(oneElem => !two.find(twoElem => oneElem === twoElem.identifier));

console.log('result: ', result);
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use a [`Set`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set) and filter the values of `one`.

```js
var one = [111, 222, 333, 444],
    two = [{ identifier: 111 }, { identifier: 222 }, { identifier: 444 } ],
    result = one.filter((s => a => !s.has(a))(new Set(two.map(o => o.identifier))));

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can map the variable two first

```js
var one = [111, 222, 333, 444];
var two = [
  { identifier: 111 },
  { identifier: 222 },
  { identifier: 444 }
];
two = two.map(function(item) {
  return item.identifier;
});

var result = one.filter(function (item) {
    return two.indexOf(item) == -1;
});

console.log('result: ', result);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a temporary array with all the values from array two. Then use indexOf to check if any value from array one is missin in array two

```js
var one = [111, 222, 333, 444];
var two = [{
    identifier: 111
  },
  {
    identifier: 222
  },
  {
    identifier: 444
  }
];
var tempArray = []
two.forEach(function(item) {
  tempArray.push(item.identifier)

})
one.forEach(function(item) {
  if (tempArray.indexOf(item) === -1) {
    console.log(item)
  }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var one = [111, 222, 333, 444];
var two = [
  { identifier: 111 },
  { identifier: 222 },
  { identifier: 444 }
];

vals = two.map(e=>{ return e['identifier']})

val = one.filter(e => { return vals.indexOf(e) == -1})
console.log(val)
```

map values into array and then filter the first array.