# JS Search in object array by using array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I want to remove all the object from a data array that contains the same id in an array of id. How can I achieve this task without looping it?

```js
const id = [1, 2];
const data = [
    {id: 1},
    {id: 2},
    {id: 3}
];
console.log(data);
```

Comment: This has been asked so many times in SO that I'll make it only as a comment: `const filtered = data.filter((item) => id.includes(item.id))`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [filtering an array of objects based on another array in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46894352/filtering-an-array-of-objects-based-on-another-array-in-javascript) and [Filter Array Not in Another Array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33577868)

Comment: [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/261593/3082296)

Answer (score 1):

You can try with [`Array.prototype.filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)

> The `filter()` method creates a new array with all elements that pass the test implemented by the provided function.

and [`Array.prototype.includes()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes):

> The `includes()` method determines whether an array includes a certain value among its entries, returning true or false as appropriate.

```js
const id = [1, 2];
const data = [
    {id: 1},
    {id: 2},
    {id: 3}
];
var res = data.filter(i => !id.includes(i.id)); 
console.log(res);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
let newData = data.filter(item => !id.includes(item.id));
console.log(newData);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `.filter()` and `.includes()` for filtering your object.

```js
const id = [1, 2];
let data = [
    {id: 1},
    {id: 2},
    {id: 3}
];

data = data.filter((item) => (!id.includes(item.id)));

console.log(data);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use method uniqBy from lodash https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.11#uniqBy

```js
const uniqArray = _.uniqBy([{ 'id': 1 }, { 'id': 2 }, { 'id': 1 }], 'id');

console.log(uniqArray)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.11/lodash.js"></script>
```